# PHP redirect refresh

Tags: php, redirect

I have a system where the user logs in and is immediately directed to a PHP page that runs some queries which it inputs into session variables. After the PHP has finished executing, it redirects the user to the main page. I would like to know how I can set it up, so that when the user refreshes the main page, it redirects them to the preceding page where the calculations can run again before the main page is displayed. I simply cannot have the two pages merged together. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

EDIT: PHP include is the closest to what I need, but the problem is that when I use AJAX to submit a form, the session variables in the first file update with new data from the database. Those variables need to stay static until an actual page refresh by the user. Does anyone know how I can include the form but make it invisible to Jquery?

Comment: `require 'calculations.php';` would be the usual way to go...

Comment: Not unless he wants to preform the login process once, which is probably the case. In which case a location heaer might be a better option.

Comment: What's the real goal here in terms of functionality? How do you define a "refresh"? What sort of values are you refreshing?

Comment: Sorry, let me expand. I need the files to be separate because I have jquery on the second page that should not see the first because it updates the PHP queries and cause everything to go hay wire. I tried using include, but that still updates all of the Session variables when Jquery is used to submit.

Comment: Why don't you structure/separate your logic better so you can update the database without touching the session?

Comment: Use Session variable

Answer (score 1):

You could store a value to the `$_SESSION` and every other load, forward to the other page.

```
// Start session
session_start();

// If the session variable is set...
if (isset($_SESSION['loadCount']) {

    // Increase the count
    $_SESSION['loadCount']++;

    // If it is even...
    if ($_SESSION['loadCount'] % 2) {

        // Reidrect
        header('Location: /calculate-again.php');
        die();

    }


} else {

    $_SESSION['loadCount'] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the login form, make it submit to `page_with_awesome_calculations_and_queries_to_session_variables.php`. Assuming **no input is sent in that page**, make your calculations queries and sessions there, and then send a Location header to the new page.

```
header('Location: 'index.php');
```

This will cause the address bar in the browser to actually change to index.php, and a refresh will make the user stick there.

You should also secure your page_with_awesome_calculations_and_queries_to_session_variables.php to not allow access unless the correct `$_POST` variables are set.

Answer (score 0):

Have `mainpage.php` receive one url parameter `t` which is the epoch timestamp.

Whenever `calculation.php` redirects to `mainpage.php` it will pass the epoch timestamp. If `mainpage.php` finds the epoch timestamp is older than five seconds, it will redirect back to `calculation.php` and exit.

*mainpage.php*

```
if (time() - $_GET['t'] > 5)
{
  header('Location: calculation.php');
  die();
}
else
{
  // proceed normally
}
```

*calculation.php*

```
// perform calculation
header('Location: calculation.php?t=' . time());
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<?
require 'calculations.php';

// Mainpage goes here
?>
```

to the top of the mainPage. This makes it an extension of the mainPage which is run before the main page is loaded.